splunk results per day and overall
I have a splunk query that gives me the average, max and percentile 95 per day of a field. I would like to add one more row on the results with the overall values.
ie
timechart span=1d avg(field), max(field), exactperc95(field)

and also
stats avg(field), max(field), exactperc95(field)




_time
avg
max
p95




2020-01-23
1.5
5
4


2020-01-24
1.2
8
7


2020-01-25
1.4
5
4


2020-01-26
1.1
7
6


overall
1.3
8
6




The appendpipe command should do the job.  It runs the current result set through the specified command(s) and adds its results to the existing results.
...
| timechart span=1d avg(field) as avg, max(field) as max, exactperc95(field) as p95
| appendpipe [ stats avg(avg) as avg, max(max) as max, exactperc95(p95) as p95 
  | eval _time = "overall" ]


This can work for  max(max) as max, but it doesnt work for avg and exactperc95

I made a copy-paste error.  Try the updated answer.

I think there ara still 2 issues :
The overall average is not the average of each days average. Similar with the exactperc95. The max is right.

Try this run-anywhere SPL:
| gentimes start=-3 increment=1h
    ```generate three days of data a 1h increments with random values in field of 0-10```
| eval field=random()%10
| rename starttime AS _time
```get the overall stats into overall_*```
| eventstats 
    avg(field) AS overall_average
    max(field) AS overall_max
    exactperc95(field) AS overall_perc95
```get the timecharts and preserve overall stats with first```
| timechart span=1d 
    avg(field) AS average
    max(field) AS max
    exactperc95(field) AS perc95
    first(overall_average) AS overall_average 
    first(overall_max) AS overall_max 
    first(overall_perc95) AS overall_perc95
    ```delete the empty day that occurs for some reason??```
| where isnotnull(max)
```create overall row```
| append [makeresults | eval _time="overall"]
    ```fill overall_* fields to overall row```
| filldown overall_*
```replace the aggregate fields in the overall row```
| eval 
    average=if(_time=="overall",overall_average,average),
    max=if(_time=="overall",overall_max,max),
    perc95=if(_time=="overall",overall_perc95,perc95)
    ```remove overall_* fields and finalize``` 
| fields - overall_* 
| table _time average max perc95

